# Visual Studios 2015 wpf c# NEED RTS ALWAYS OFF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, serial-port

I communicate via RS232 line to a piece of equipment which requires RTS to always be OFF.  If RTS is raised for even a fraction of a second, then it goes into a Firmware Updating mode.

I am converting a program from Java/Netbeans to Visual Studios/WPF/C#.  In Java I have had no problems keeping RTS off, so there is no hardware or bios problem.  However, with Visual Studios I just can not find a solution.

I can control the RTS line after a COM port is opened, but it seems during the OPEN process RTS is always raised for a small fraction of a second.

I set serialPort.RtsEnable=false, DtrEnable=false, handshake= none.  It seems during the OPEN process RTS is raised momentarily and then lowered per what I specify with the RtsEnable property.

Maybe someone has experience with this and has a solution?

`public virtual Boolean connect(
            String portName,
            Boolean DTR,
            Boolean RTS,
            int baudRate,
            int databits,
            System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopbits,
            System.IO.Ports.Parity parity,
            System.IO.Ports.Handshake handshake)
        {`

```
        Boolean success = false;
        try
        {
            serialPort.PortName = portName; // COMx or COMxx 
            serialPort.DtrEnable = DTR;
            serialPort.RtsEnable = RTS;
            serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
            serialPort.DataBits = databits;
            serialPort.StopBits = stopbits;
            serialPort.Parity = parity;
            serialPort.Handshake = handshake;

            serialPort.Open();
            //serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            Console.WriteLine("Port " + serialPort.PortName + " is opened. " + serialPort.BaudRate + " " + serialPort.DtrEnable + " " + serialPort.RtsEnable);
            success = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Port " + serialPort.PortName + " is in use.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to open port " + serialPort.PortName);
        }

        return success;
    } // end of method connect
```

Comment: To be honest, using the RTS line as an update mechanism is not a very good idea, if the hardware is yours maybe you can change how to fire the upgrade. Else, if your program will not fire the upgrade then you can disconnect the RTS line physically.

Comment: Gusman, yes the hardware manufacturer recommends making a custom cable with the RTS wire disconnected.  And use a normal cable for firmware upgrades.  But, I'd like to avoid that solution if possible.

Comment: It is a chicken-and-egg problem.  Before you can control DTR, you must first open the port.  At which point the driver applies default settings, that very often turns on DTR.  Getting that brief blip to make the device inoperable is idiotic, but otherwise a pretty genial scheme.  Device manufacturers pull off all kinds of tricks like that to get you to buy extra hardware with a 500% markup.  Resistance is futile, buy it or get the side-cutters out.

Comment: Hans.  You meant to type RTS, but I understand.